# How to move an API Key (some random string) from model code to config/initializers folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am little confused on how to do this. So I have an API key api_key = 9173917789173 but I don't want to directly put in the model but want to define it in somewhere in config/initializers folder and then want to use the variable only in model.

How to do this ?

Here is what my code looks like app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
def get_api_data
    use_data = http://example.com/?key=9173917789173
end
```

I want to make it

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
def get_api_data
    use_data = http://example.com/?key=API_KEY
end
```

and I want to define API_KEY in config/initializers

Comment: Use just need to create a file in config/initalizers and put API_KEY = 9173917789173 here

Comment: Take a look at [Figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) for another solution.

Comment: @BlueSmith - so there is no such thing as class scope and I can define it just like that and use it anywhere ?

Comment: It's up to you, you can define global constants or wrap them in a class/module. Then you can use them anywhere in the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file with any name in `config/initializers` like `api.rb`.  In it you could put your API_KEY as a global constant as @Blue Smith says:

```
API_KEY = 9173917789173
```

Or you could store it in rails configuration like

```
Rails.application.config.api_key = 9173917789173
```

Or you could save it as a constant in the model class:

```
User::API_KEY = 9173917789173
```